# Self Escrow Smart Contract Not Paying Out Money

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, escrow

I have a self escrow contract deployed on the Rinkeby Test Network. The goal of this contract is to store the owner's money for a period of time, and then pay it back when that period is over.
Here is the code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

/**
 * @title Storage
 * @dev Store & retrieve value in a variable
 * @custom:dev-run-script ./scripts/deploy_with_ethers.ts
 */
contract Storage {

    int public start_date;
    address payable public owner;
    uint public amount_stored;
    int public timeOut;

    event Escrow(address owner, int time_out, uint amount_stored);

    constructor() payable {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function enter(int timeOutArg) public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0.001 ether, "not enough eth");
        require(timeOutArg < 10000 && timeOutArg > 0, "time out is not valid");
        require(msg.sender == owner, "you are not the owner");
        amount_stored = msg.value;
        start_date = int(block.timestamp);
        timeOut = timeOutArg;
        emit Escrow(owner, timeOutArg, msg.value);
    }

    function getTimeLeft() public view returns (int) {
        return start_date - int(block.timestamp)  + timeOut;
    }

    function payMoneyOut() public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "you are not the owner");
        require(getTimeLeft() < 5 || getTimeLeft() > 10000, "escrow is not done yet");
        owner.transfer(amount_stored);
    }
}
```

When I call the enter function it works fine, but when I call payMoneyOut it prompts me to pay for gas for the contract, but the contract never sends me the money that I paid in with enter.
This is the [link](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xab847Dd1939ebdAfaCcE7748175A87BEb8E95961) to the contract on Ethscan. I'm developing with the Mixer IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [transaction log](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x8636b18e93d5767d47e0d627e573603f1b7b51826629101c71a3995359088969), under the "To" field, you can see the Ether was actually being sent back to you:
`TRANSFER  0.01 Ether From 0xab847dd1939ebdafacce7748175a87beb8e95961 To  0xd455b4c1485a3fe2af431dfa9451100b30bcbef6`

Comment: Oh, I did not catch that, thanks! How come my balance is not updated in my metamask wallet?

Comment: Welcome :) Hmm, I don't know. Maybe you're on the wrong account or network? I would probably try switching these back and forth.